# VK API Как скачать видео со стороннего ресурса?

Tags: android, vkontakte-api

Видеоролики, которые расположены на сторонних ресурсах, ВК отдает без прямых ссылок, а именно на само видео. Например, если видео с YouTube, то ссылка ведет на страницу с этим видео. Скачивание не работает, вернее качается файл .html с подсказкой включить JavaScript. Как тогда скачать файл? Замечаю, что некоторые видео залиты не только на YouTube, например, на RuTube. Тем не менее название сайта содержится в ответе JSON. Тоесть можно в зависимости от него вызывать разные алгоритмы для закачки. Тогда где можно узнать полный список всех возможных ресурсов? И, вообще, может есть какое-то готовое решение?

Comment: Вопрос хороший. Я подозреваю, что готового решения не существует, покуда у каждого сервиса есть своё API. Было бы круто создать что-то универсальное. Но, думаю, что этого нет. Если найдёте, киньте сюда ссыль. Буду очень благодарен. Передо мной частенько подобного рода задачи встают.

Comment: @hedgehogues, вы прям вовремя, смотрите, что я раздобыл )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Взбесили приложения, в которых эта функция недоступна, разрабы очень ленивые и, к тому же, говнокодеры (посмотрите на длительность, они перевели секунды в миллисекунды зачем-то). Прикладываю скриншоты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашел сайт - http://getvideo.at

Его API. X3 как, но получилось наобум, может это где-то написано, но я не нашел, странно, что GET запрос)

```
http://getvideo.at/search?q=ссылка
```

В качестве ссылки можно указать любой URL **даже с YouTube**. Сервер отдаст JSON обьект с прямыми ссылками, по которым и надо качать видео со сторонних ресурсов.

P.S Google, sorry

**UPD**

Подключился! Volley не работал, так как на сайте какая-то проблема с сертификатами. Пришлось писать `HttpUrlConnection` в ... `AsyncTask` :( Кому интересно - скину код